# UWP Temporary folder cleaning

Tags: uwp

I would like to know if the temporary folder of the application is emptied automatically. If so, when is this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Temporary folder can be cleaned up automatically whenever the device reaches a low-storage threshold.

> The temporary app data store works like a cache. Its files do not roam and could be removed at any time. **The System Maintenance task can automatically delete data stored at this location at any time.** The user can also clear files from the temporary data store using Disk Cleanup. Temporary app data can be used for storing temporary information during an app session. **There is no guarantee that this data will persist beyond the end of the app session as the system might reclaim the used space if needed.**

The key point here is that anything you put in Temporary folder cannot be relied upon at a later time/after the current app session. For more info, please see [Temporary app data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#temporary-app-data).

And here are some best practices for Temporary folder:

1. **Use Temporary for any intermediate or temporary files.** If you won’t need a file after your app is terminated or suspended, this is the right location for it.
2. **Clean your Temp folder during app initialization.** If you are writing large amounts of data to Temp, it is a good idea to clear it when your app is initialized to avoid the system or the user having to take action to free up storage.